# IphoneX screen not covering header and footer in cordova project

Tags: ios, cordova, screen, iphone-x

My application is not iPhoneX compatible, searched a lot and tried many different things. the splash screen is showing just fine on every device but the inner screens not covering the header and footer. Using the same image sizes which suggested to make the full screen.
Also using the view-port in meta tag index.html file in head tag.

Using cordova 7.1.0 and using ios 4.5.4 versions in my cordova project the application is just running fine on all the devices but its not compatible for iPhoneX screen. when run the project on iphonex in simulator it left the white space on header and footer.

Using the below images size for splash and the meta tag in head tag in index.html file.

```
<splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/750x1334.png" />
        <splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/1242x2208.png" />
        <splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/1278x732.png" />
        <splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/1334x750.png" />
        <splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/1334x1334.png" />
        <splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/2208x1242.png" />
        <splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/2208x2208.png" />
        <splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/2732x2732.png" />
```

and the meta tag in head tag :

Answer (score 1):

**LaunchScreen/SplashScreen**

After complete iOS Build Go to ->

`Projectpath -> Platform ->iOS ->Open Project in Xcode`
In Xcode
`ProjectName -> Resources -> Images.xcassets -> LaunchImage`
[image]

**Header:**
Add Cordova statusbar Plugin
`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar`

**config.xml**
In config file add below preferences

```
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#00458D" />
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="blacktranslucent" />
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarDefaultScrollToTop" value="false" />
```

**Footer:** 
 In every .html page add below code inside `<head>` tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
```

Comment: Thanks Ramprasath for your help. 
But I already tried this to cover the screen "<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />" with color by using this only header is getting cover not the footer. Footer is still have white space. Your solution is totally same which I had tried.
Thanks again

Comment: @DipanshuGupta pls add your full code. It helps to find the problem. Thanks..!

Comment: Please check the code below. I am using cordova onsen ui templated for screens.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Ramprasath selvam here is my config file    
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
        <widget id="" version="4.2.58" versionCode="29" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
            <name>Mobile App</name>
            <description>
                Mobile App.
            </description>
            <author email="" href="http://cordova.io">
                Mobile App
            </author>
            <allow-navigation href="*" />
            <content src="index.html" />
            <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
            <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-8.1.1" />
            <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
            <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
            <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
            <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
            <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
            <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
            <gap:plugin name="com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk" source="npm" />
            <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" />
            <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" />
            <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" />
            <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="1.0.1" />
            <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" />
            <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy" source="npm" spec="2.2.0" />
            <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-toast" source="npm" spec="2.6.0" />
            <gap:plugin source="git" spec="https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-cordova.git" />
            <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="3.0.0" />
            <gap:plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" source="npm" spec="4.0.3" />
            <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps-plus" source="npm">
                <param name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="AIzaSyDAwrq1ial39lAGZx6jx0WZdZ-Qg4Z94cs" />
                <param name="API_KEY_FOR_IOS" value="AIzaSyBDr3nwlBEV87jriUmR2y6vb0CeipfWczE" />
            </gap:plugin>
            <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-buildinfo" source="npm" spec="1.1.0" />
            <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" source="npm">
                <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="com.googleusercontent.apps.402245806775-vsnc22opbodba6qslf77631tkumik7fe" />
            </gap:plugin>
            <gap:plugin name="cordova-launch-review" source="npm" />
            <platform name="android" />
            <platform name="ios" />
            <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
            <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
            <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
            <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
            <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#00458D" />
            <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="blacktranslucent" />
            <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
            <preference name="StatusBarDefaultScrollToTop" value="false" />
            <access origin="*" />
            <access launch-external="yes" origin="tel:*" />
            <gap:config-file parent="/manifest" platform="android">
                <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
                <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
                </application>
            </gap:config-file>
            <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.0.1" />
            <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="2.4.1" />
            <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="1.6.2" />
            <gap:plugin source="git" spec="https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin.git" />
            <platform name="ios">
                <config-file parent="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
                    <string>App want to always use your location</string>
                </config-file>
                <config-file parent="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
                    <string>App wants to use your location</string>
                </config-file>
            </platform>
            <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSCameraUsageDescription">
                <string>need camera access to take pictures</string>
            </edit-config>
            <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
                <string>need to photo library access to get pictures from there</string>
            </edit-config>
            <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
                <string>need location access to find things nearby</string>
            </edit-config>
            <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription">
                <string>need to photo library access to save pictures there</string>
            </edit-config>
            <platform name="ios">
                <config-file parent="com.apple.developer.in-app-payments" target="*-Debug.plist">
                    <array>
                        <string></string>
                    </array>
                </config-file>
                <config-file parent="com.apple.developer.in-app-payments" target="*-Release.plist">
                    <array>
                        <string></string>
                    </array>
                </config-file>
            </platform>
            <platform name="android">
                <resource-file src="www/beep.wav" target="res/raw/beep.wav" />
                <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
                <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
                <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
                <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
                <icon density="xxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
                <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
                <splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
                <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
                <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
                <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
                <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
                <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
                <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
                <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
                <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
                <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
                <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
                <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
            </platform>
            <platform name="ios">
                <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
                <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
                <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
                <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
                <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
                <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
                <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
                <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
                <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
                <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
                <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
                <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
                <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
                <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
                <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
                <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
                <icon height="1024" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon@xcopy.png" width="1024" />
                <splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/750x1334.png" />
                <splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/1242x2208.png" />
                <splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/1278x732.png" />
                <splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/1334x750.png" />
                <splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/1334x1334.png" />
                <splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/2208x1242.png" />
                <splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/2208x2208.png" />
                <splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/2732x2732.png" />
            </platform>
            <engine name="android" spec="^6.4.0" />
            <engine name="osx" spec="^4.0.1" />
            <engine name="ios" spec="^4.5.4" />
            <engine name="browser" spec="^5.0.3" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^2.0.1" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.1" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="^5.2.1">
                <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="com.googleusercontent.apps.402245806775-vsnc22opbodba6qslf77631tkumik7fe" />
            </plugin>
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-toast" spec="^2.6.0" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps-plus" spec="^1.4.1">
                <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_IOS" value="AIzaSyBDr3nwlBEV87jriUmR2y6vb0CeipfWczE" />
            </plugin>
            <plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" spec="^4.0.3" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebookads" spec="^4.23.2" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^2.0.2" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="^1.7.1" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-buildinfo" spec="^2.0.1" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^4.0.1" />
            <plugin name="cordova-launch-review" spec="^3.1.1" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="^0.1.20" />
            <plugin name="uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator" spec="^4.2.1">
                <variable name="OKHTTP_VERSION" value="3.+" />
                <variable name="LOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="This app requires access to your location for navigation purposes" />
            </plugin>
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^2.4.1">
                <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value=" " />
                <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value=" " />
            </plugin>
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy" spec="git+https://github.com/bastikikang/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy.git">
                <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="11.6.2" />
            </plugin>
            <plugin name="com.cmackay.plugins.googleanalytics" spec="^1.0.4">
                <variable name="ANALYTICS_VERSION" value="11.6.2" />
            </plugin>
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-google-analytics" spec="^1.8.6">
                <variable name="GMS_VERSION" value="11.0.1" />
            </plugin>
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.3.0" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-applepay" spec="^5.0.0" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.1.0" />
            <plugin name="com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk" spec="^3.5.0" />
        </widget>


Inside index file: 
<script type="text/ons-template" id="home1.html">
  <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="sNavigator"> 
    <ons-page id="page-home1" on-device-backbutton="exitKApp();">
 <!--      <div class="full_bg">
      <div class="logSection">
      <img src="css/images/FS-Logo-117.9x116.8.png" class="centerimg">
      <p class="FoodSquireText mt10">FoodSquire</p>
       <span class="textspan">Local Delivery <br> and Easier Pickup</span>
      </div>

       <div class="externalDiv">
          <button class="SeeBtn" onclick="showSignupForm();">GET STARTED</button>
           <div class="registerBtn">
          <button class="alreadyactBtn" onclick="showLogin(1);">I already have an account  <i class="material-icons IconsAlign arrow-right pdr5">arrow_forward</i></button> </div>
        </div>
        </div>  --> 

         <!-- New design By Balvant-->

        <section id="new-external-homepage">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="css/images/mixed-plate.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="bottom">
            <img src="css/images/food-squire-logo-white.svg" class="logo" alt="">
            <h1>LOCAL DELIVERY AND <br> EASIER PICKUP</h1>
            <div>
              <button onclick="showSignupForm();">GET STARTED</button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showLogin(1);">I already have an account <img src="css/images/right-arrow-1.svg" alt=""></a>
              <div onClick="applePay()">apple pay</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

        <!-- end -->

  </ons-page>
</ons-navigator >
</script>
```